# SSH access failure from Ubuntu to Windows XP FreeSSHd

Tags: virtualbox, openssh

I installed 2 VMs on VirtualBox.

1. VM 1: 
   Windows XP with [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) and [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) installed.
   IP address: 10.0.0.2
2. VM 2:
    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition with [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) installed.
   IP address: 10.0.0.3

From VM 1, I run [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) with the IP address of VM 2 (10.0.0.3) and port number 22. I get prompted to input the username and password of VM 2 and everything works fine.
From VM 2, I run on the terminal (Ubuntu): `ssh username_of_vm1@10.0.0.2` , I get prompted to enter the password of VM 1. I do so, but it says my password is invalid (while it is the correct one). I even deactived the Firewall on VM 1, but still the problem is here: my password is not accepted from VM 2.
 Is this due to some settings maybe I must do on VM 1 (Windows XP) so as I can access it with SSH ? Maybe it has something to do with the Firewall of Windows XP ?
*Important information:* 
`ping 10.0.0.2` from VM 1 and `ping 10.0.0.3` from VM 2 are working successfully.

Comment: Freesshd is installed on win like service and is up and running?

Comment: I installed FreeSSHd  as  a system service on VM 1 (Windows XP)

Comment: Check this [manual](http://silosix.com/2013/index.php?pid=175&section=IT). I very good and heva all that you need

Comment: Check if on VM1 there is any firewall active (the rules can be asymmetric).

Comment: @Hastur: yes, the firewall is active. Do you think Firewall disables SSH access ?

Comment: I cannot know from here: disable it to check if it is so. After you can enable it again and start to see how to put rules. :-)

Comment: I deactivated it but i still can not access it. There is an improvement now, however (but before I deactivated Firewall): on VM 2 i get prompted to enter the password. I do so, but it says my password is wrong while it is a valid one.

Comment: Add a user in FreeSSHd Configuration and login with that user.

Comment: @AbdulKadir Thank you very much, I did what you said and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AbdulKadir just wrote me in the comment above, all what I needed is to add a user with a password on FreeSSHd. That way I am able to access finally Windows with SSH.